# Adding external factors to a time series model

Tags: time-series, python, forecasting, predictor, intermittent-time-series

I've been working on time series for a while now and using [Hierarchical time series forecasting](https://otexts.com/fpp3/hierarchical.html#hierarchical), Croston TSB methods for demand forecasting. I want to add external factors which affect the forecasting say for example an increase in one of the factor decreases the demand.

when I've explored this I've come across adding exogenous regressors to the model but in my case, I don't know the future values of exogenous regressors so it didn't help. Is there any other way in time series to add the external factors that affect the forecasting?